# Looping through a recordset twice

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I'm developping a Moodle 2.9.1 pluggin and I need to loop through a small recordset twice on the same page.

I'm using

```
$rs = $DB->get_recordset_sql($sql, array());
```

to get the data from mysql.

I would need a function like mysql `data_seek(0)` to work on the recordset again but I cannot find anything related to this in the moodle API or forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the data is not going to be excessively huge, then you can use get_records_sql() instead. This will return an array, indexed by the first field in the SELECT. You can then do what you want with this array (loop through it multiple times, split, pop, shift, etc).

Comment: oh god... I did try get_records_sql instead of recordset and couldn't make it work but after trying again it's fine... (probably because I still had the line $rs->close();)

Answer (score 0):

Just loop twice through $rs ??

```
foreach ($rs as $data){
}
foreach ($rs as $data){
}
```

Or to do it clean make a function loop_thorught and call it twice ?